# Creating webhook using asana API

Tags: node.js, webhooks, openai-api, asana, asana-api

I am integrating the Asana with the Open AI API for which I am trying to establish the webhook in the asana using the asana API.

But I am getting the 403 error.

Please find the API details :

Method : POST
URL : https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/webhooks
Body :

```
{
  "data": {
    "target": "{url}/recievewebhook",
    "resource": "{Workspace_ID}",
    "filters": [
      {
        "action": "added",
        "resource_type": "task",
        "resource_subtype": "default_task"
      },
      {
        "action": "changed",
        "resource_type": "task",
        "resource_subtype": "default_task"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the error I am getting is :

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "error": "invalid_filters_for_larger_scoped_webhooks",
            "message": "Webhooks for larger scoped resources must have at least one filter and all filters must be in our whitelist.",
            "user_message": "Webhooks for larger scoped resources must have at least one filter and all filters must be in our whitelist.",
            "help": "For more information on API status codes and how to handle them, read the docs on errors: https://developers.asana.com/docs/errors"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thankyou so much in advance.

I am expecting the 200ok response from the API. So that if I create any task on my workspace I should get the notification about the event with its details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like webhook events from tasks don't propagate to the team/workspace level. We might be stuck at receiving task events at the project level until Asana allows access to tasks from higher levels.

From their [docs](https://developers.asana.com/docs/webhooks-guide#filtering):

> To reduce the volume of data to transfer, webhooks created on team, portfolio, or workspace must specify filters. In addition, the set of event filters that can be placed on a team-level or workspace-level webhook is more limited than filters for webhooks that are created on lower-level resources:

> Webhook events from tasks, subtasks, and stories won't be propagated to these higher-level webhooks, so all changes on these resources are automatically filtered out.